# How can I write a for loop that makes X many api request in parallel?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

How can I write a `for` loop using callbacks, promises, whatever it takes, so a loop will loop its self, each time making a request to a different api, and then pooling the results in an array so I can send that to the client side.

e.g.

```
var streams = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
var result  = [];
for (var i = 0; i < streams.length; i++) {
   // Get Stream Data through api request
   // Asynchronously do this so that the loop doesn't have to wait to continue for increased performance
   result.push({streamName: "Blah", viewers: 123});
}

// Wait till loop is done and all call backs are back (maybe Promise.all?)

res.json({streamData: result});
```

I don't see the need in having to make the loop wait for each `get` request to finish, rather than have them all run at once (obviously for increased performance).

How might I be able to accomplish this? Thanks.

Comment: Use a recursive function that calls itself upon completion of the API request and moves on if it is done with all of the requests.

Comment: `Promise.all()` should return expected results; could also include `onRejected` callback if an error in one of api calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library for that kind of cases. Typical solution below using [`async.each`](https://github.com/caolan/async#collections-1)

```
//don't forget `npm install async --save`
var async = require('async');
var streams = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
var result  = [];
async.each(streams, function(stream, callback){
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        result.push({streamName: 'Blah', viewers: 128});
        callback(); 
    }, 1000); 
    //for demo only, use your database call here
    //or any kind of async requests you would like, 
    //just call `callback` without arguments for success, 
    //or pass argument for error, callback(err);
}, function(err){
    if(err) {
        res.status(400).send(err);
    } else {
        res.send({streamData: result});
    }
});
```

It's pretty useful and big library, so follow up [async.js](/questions/tagged/async.js) for questions that may occur

Comment: Whoever down voted, would be awesome to have a comment